# Date picker window is not close

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker, input-mask

I have a date picker but When I clicked date picker input and if I didn't choise any date then when I go outside the input, date picker window is not close. Also this problem just is there in IE.

My code is below;

```
  @Html.TextBox("Birthdate", null, new { @class = "form-control date-picker input-mask-date", placeholder = "Doğum Tarihi", required = true, id = "dtBirthDate" })
```

Script side;

```
$(".input-mask-date").mask("99.99.9999");
```

if I didn't choise any date then when I go outside the input, date picker window is not close.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned this is an issue with IE. However, you can add a custom function to check when one leaves or clicks outside the datepicker to hide it.

```
$('.date-picker').on('blur', function() {
  $('.date-picker').unmask();
});
```

You can equally use *focusOut* for the event listener and also *fadeOut / slideUp* if they work on date pickers.

So as mentioned by @caglarboran, the right method to call is *unmask* rather than hide. Edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks for showing the way. I shared how I solved.

Comment: Great that my answer led you to it. You can be generous with a vote

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem like that;

```
$('#dtBirthDate').on('focus', function () {
    $(this).mask("99.99.9999");
});

$("#dtBirthDate").focusout(function () {
    $(this).unmask();
});
```